# Ad by advertise on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-plugin

Здравствуйте. У меня возникла проблема в использовании плагина Wordpress и при hover -e на некоторые слова появляется вирус Ad by Advertise. Но при проверке на anti-malware все файлы чистые.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress ни при чем. Ads by Advertise - это вирус в локальном (вашем) компьютере. Как его чистить, можно почитать, например, [тут](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-by-advertise-removal/).